# sql alchemy scalar query issue?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

what's wrong with this query.

```
self.connection.execute(select([func.count(table.c.id)]).as_scalar())
```

this give me this traceback

```
StatementError: Not an executable clause (original cause: ArgumentError: 
     Not an executable clause) '(SELECT count(table.id) AS count_1 \nFROM agent)'
```

or how can I get the number of all rows in a table using **SqlAlchemy Core**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need to use .as_scalar() method. This method is intended to be used for creating subquery object. And subquery object is used to build another queries, and not to be executed directly.

From your code it seems that you are building select query to be executed:

In this case the following code would be sufficient:

```
self.connection.execute(select([func.count(table.c.id)]))
```

The following code works without exception:

```
r = engine.execute(select([func.count(table.c.id)]))
print r
for i in r:
    print i
```

result:

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x032F4E30>
(1,)
```

**PS:**
From the sqlalchemy documentation:
[The Query Object: as_scalar](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar)

> as_scalar()
>
> Return the full SELECT statement represented by this
>   Query, converted to a scalar subquery.